# Django: How to save the POST.get of a checkbox as false (0) in a DataBase?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to save the value of a checkbox as true or false in a database. I have to use a model for this. If the box is checked the value of '1' is saved. However, if the box is not checked I get the error message:

```
Django Version:     1.9.4
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    (1048, "Column 'completed' cannot be null")
```

Currently my setup looks like this:

In models.py I have:

```
class myClass(models.Model): 
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
```

In views.py I have:

```
def create_myClass(request):
    completed = request.POST.get('completed')
    toSave = models.myClass(completed=completed)
    toSave.save()
```

and in the HTML I have:

```
<label class="col-md-5" for="completed"> Completed: </label>
<input id="completed" type="checkbox" name="completed">
```

I've tried to set required = False in the BooleanField as some other posts suggested but then get the error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'`.

I've also tried to set 'completed' to False in views.py like:

```
if request.POST.get('completed', False ):
    commpleted = False
```

and

```
completed = request.POST.get('completed')
if completed == 'null':
    commpleted = False
```

But neither work (not sure if my syntax is correct?)

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can print the value of `request.POST` to see what you are getting in the views.

If you have not specified a `value` attribute in the checkbox HTML element, the default value which will passed in the `POST` is `on` if the checkbox is checked.

In the views you can check if the value of `completed` is `on`:

```
# this will set completed to True, only if the value of 
# `completed` passed in the POST is on 
completed = request.POST.get('completed', '') == 'on'
```

If the checkbox is not checked, then nothing will be passed and in that case you will get `False` from above statement.

---

I would suggest that you use a [Django ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) if you can so most of the things are automatically taken care for you.

Comment: The project manager specifically wanted the models like this because he wants to use them for other things (not 100% sure all the reasoning honestly).

Comment: completed = request.POST.get('completed', '') == 'on' seems to work! Thank you very very much!

Comment: Well, model and forms are two different things in the case. You already have a model now you need to to associate it with a form so it can take of rendering it in the UI and then processing the data you have submitted. You can read more about how this work in the link above.

Comment: @SuperCow: Please follow [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as well if the answer helped you.

Answer (score 2):

```
completed = request.POST.get('completed')
completed = True if completed else False
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use this code snippet

```
def create_myClass(request):
    completed = request.POST.get('completed')
    if not completed:
        completed = False
    toSave = models.myClass(completed=completed)
    toSave.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

To tackle that problem you have to know how checkboxes work: if they are checked, a value is passed to `request.POST` -- but if a checkbox isn't checked, no value will be passed **at all**. So if the statement

```
'completed' in request.POST
```

is true, the checkbox has been checked (because only then 'completed' has been sent and is in the POST array), otherwise it hasn't.

I like this way more because it doesn't deal w/ any fancy default values, but is a plain and simple condition.

```
completed = 'completed' in request.POST
toSave = models.myClass( completed = completed )
toSave.save()
```