# How to POST run time data in views using form in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I write data in particular div section using ajax, Now i want to POST this data in views.py but it returns None. when i write manully like `<input type='checkbox' id='filesid' name = 'filesname' value='abc'>` abc. It returns value. jquery also works fine for that. 
html code

```
html_code = "<input type='checkbox' id='filesid' name = 'filesname' value='"+i+"'>"+i+"<br>"

$('#runtime-div').html(html_code);
```

another html page where form is used

```
<form  action = '/home/update_file/' id="UpdateDataFiles" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return myUpdateFile()">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id='runtime-div' class="card-body">

    </div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
filename = request.POST.get('filesname')
print(filename)
```

Comment: A checkbox field is sent in the request only if the value is true (only if the checkbox is checked). Else it will not be passed in the request

Comment: Yes I want only checked value, but it return None

Comment: Is the checkbox checked in the UI when you submit the form? and when do you add the field to the DOM?

Comment: Check box load when i click radio button. when i use jquery for alert it 's fine with that checkbox. but it didn't POST into views, i don't know why?

Comment: Probably you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716303/django-how-to-save-the-post-get-of-a-checkbox-as-false-0-in-a-database?rq=1

Comment: It's different problem